# Multiple routes with differents parameters for the same action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently building an ASP.NET project with differents routes for the same method. My current code is:

```
 [Route("evenements/categories/{slug}-{id}")]
 [Route("evenements/ville/{name}")]
 [Route("evenements/listing")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Listing(string slug = null, int id = 0, string name = null)
```

And I'm using `ControllerContext.RouteData.Route` to detect which route I'm matching, for now, it's working perfectly fine. Unfortunately, when I use `@Url.Action` to build my URL, it does not properly work and I end up with `evenements/listing?name=` or `evenements/listing?slug=&id=`.

If I enter the URL myself (like `https://localhost:44396/evenements/categories/musique-1016`) it works properly, but it's not properly generated otherwise.

How could I do it without having to write the route myself in my template?

Comment: Allow me to say that this is a bad approach which is inherently error prone. You should really create different action methods per different parameters allowed, avoiding the use of optional *route* parameters.

Comment: This is what I had previously, but since all these action just show the same page, I found it a bit redundant. The different url are just there for SEO reason. Another option would be to just render the same View over and over.

Answer (score 2):

You may use named routes in conjunction with `Url.RouteUrl` helper inside your views when generating URLs:

```
[Route("evenements/categories/{slug}-{id}", Name = "EvenementsByCategories")]
[Route("evenements/ville/{name}", Name = "EvenementsByVille")]
[Route("evenements/listing", Name = "EvenementsListing")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Listing(string slug = null, int id = 0, string name = null)
```

View:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("EvenementsByCategories", new { slug = "mySlug", id = 1 })">My Link</a>
```